# shell: for loop returns a syntax error

Tags: shell

please I have a code that return an error I don't know way.

```
#!/bin/bash
YESTERDAY="$(date -d '1 day ago' '+%Y%m%d')"

LOGDIR=/tm/

for ssp in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};do

    for hour in {00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23};do
    logFilee="$LOGDIR"log_$YESTERDAY"$hour"_s_$ssp.txt
    logFile2e="$LOGDIR"log_$YESTERDAY"$hour"_s_dr_$ssp.txt
    echo $logFilee
    echo $logFile2e



    done;
done;
```

the output  is :

```
/tmp/log_20141022{00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23}_s_{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.txt
/tmp/log_20141022{00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23}_s_dr_{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.txt
```

this output is not correct!

thank you

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. The script you wrote works as expected for me.

Comment: How are you running the script? If you run it as `sh scriptname`, it will be executed by `sh`, not by `bash`. There's no point in using the `{foo,bar,...}` syntax anyway; you can just write `for ssp in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ; do`

Comment: I run it with sh command but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to write it as:

```
for ssp in {1..8}; do
    for hour in {00..23}; do
        ...
    done
done
```

If you don't have bash 4 then you can instead use:

```
for ssp in {1..8}; do
    for hour in $(seq -w 0 23); do
        ...
    done
done
```

Comment: I tried it but the output isn't correct:

/tmp/log_2014102200,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23_s_1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.txt

tmp/log_2014102200,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23_s_drc_1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.txt

Comment: Where are those commas coming from? There are no commas in my answer.

Comment: I copied and past your code, I think is a list ! but I don't know way!